How to execute mpg123 at given time with at
I was testing few things, nothing is working.
I have this command called ~/bin/beep for sound notifications.
#!/bin/bash

mpg123 -q /home/kuba/Pobrane/beep-6.mp3

I usually use it like this:
sleep 4m && beep

and I'm trying to execute it at the give time with at. I was testing by specifing next minute.
I was trying:
at 14:01 < ~/bin/beep
echo "/home/kuba/bin/beep" | at 14:01

I also put:
mpg123 -q /home/kuba/Pobrane/beep-6.mp3 2> /home/kuba/at.log

No error, no sound.
How should I execute mpg123 with at?


How to execute mpg123 at given time with at

Not at all! Instead, and this solves your problem (at least it does for me!), you want to run your player in the context of your user session (which means as long as you're logged in, you'll hear your beep), not with at, but with systemd-run.
systemd-run --user --on-active 30 /usr/bin/mplayer "/home/marcus/Music/Intro Of 03 - Welcome Home - Coheed and Cambria.opus"
#           ^      ^           ^  ^
#           |      |           |  |
#           \------------------------ Tell systemd-run that you want this to be 
#                  |           |  |   run within the scope of your user session
#                  |           |  |   (and not as head- and soundless system
#                  |           |  |   service)
#                  |           |  |
#                  \----------------- --on-active tells after how many seconds af-
#                              |  |   ter activation the task is executed.
#                              |  |    
#                              \----- How many seconds? 30. But you could also en-
#                                 |   ter things like "3h4min".
#                                 |
#                                 \-- the command to be executed.

systemd-run --user runs something as a service in the user scope. With --on-active you can specify the time until execution, but you can also use --on-calendar to specify things that happen regularly (e.g. every Tuesday at 11:00, or ever 10 minutes).

Because you seem surprised by at not working for your purpose: It can't!
What at does is sending a message to a daemon (atd, specifically). That daemon handles all the sleeping-until-it's-time, and then the execution of the job.
Now, means that the job is executed within the context of that daemon. Sure, the daemon will fork of a process, change the user to the user that called at (at itself is runs as root, it's a setuid program, and honestly, that's a terrible choice, but here we are), but what it can't do is recreate all your desktops session environment that sets up the sound system that mpg123 uses to be allowed to play sound.
So, that's a dead end. Personally, I think you shouldn't use at at all; it's so incompletely documented in architecture and accepted date formats that it's a bit of a liability. And as mentioned, at runs setuid, for no specific reason at all (it needs to communicate with a root-running service anyways), and it doesn't do what you expect it to do, anyways. It's a 1980s, at latest a pre-1994 design. It's really not good.

So this looks the same as sleep 30s && /usr/bin/mplayer "/home/marcus/Music/Intro Of 03 - Welcome Home - Coheed and Cambria.opus" you only have more typing. Also, sleep is easier to remember.

no, sorry, it doesn't look like that at all, and my answer goes into depth in what it does differently. It runs something in the current user's scope, but as services, not as something started within your current shell.

I don't see any benefit, I was asking about specific time, but here it will need to do exactly the same and put number of seconds. I can do this with sleep.

you seem to have not read what I wrote under the code. --on-calendar does exactly what you need.

That's not really what it's intended for.
The primary use for at is scheduling jobs (tasks, commands, or scripts) for automating system tasks, managing cron jobs and scheduled tasks you run at regular intervals.
Here's a countdown to execution script.
#!/bin/bash

secs="$1"

seconds=$(date +%s)
date1=$((seconds + $secs))

while [ "$date1" -ge "$(date +%s)" ]; do
    echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - $(date +%s))) +%H:%M:%S)\r"
done

# Your command here

notify-send "Command executed."

exit 0

Save as: exec_countdown.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x exec_countdown.sh
Usage: ./exec_countdown.sh [seconds] &disown
The terminal will echo the PID of the background process.
To abort: kill [PID from terminal]

Fedora's repository: calc, tcalc, or mucalc.


Don't want to mess with conversion calculations?Here's a GUI you can use.  I've created a scheduler with yad.

#!/bin/bash

command=""
execution_time=""
current_time="00:00:00"

choice=$(yad --borders=10 --window-icon="appointment-new" \
--image="appointment-new" --image-on-top --title "Command Scheduler" \
--form \
--field="Command:" "$command" \
--field="Execution Date::DT" "" \
--field="Time (HH:MM:SS)::TM" "$current_time" \
--field="Include notification?:CHK" \
--button="Confirm"!gtk-apply:0 \
--button="Cancel"!application-exit:1)

# Get the exit code
exit_code=$?

# Process the result
if [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]]; then
    # User clicked "Execute"
    command=$(echo "$choice" | cut -d'|' -f1)
    execution_date=$(echo "$choice" | cut -d'|' -f2)
    execution_time=$(echo "$choice" | cut -d'|' -f3)
    notify=$(echo "$choice" | cut -d'|' -f4)

    # Combine date and time
    execution_datetime="$execution_date $execution_time"

    # Calculate seconds until execution
    current_time=$(date +%s)
    execution_time=$(date -d "$execution_datetime" +%s)
    time_diff=$((execution_time - current_time))

    if [[ $time_diff -le 0 ]]; then
        yad --error --text="Please select a future date and time."
        exit 1
    fi

    # Schedule the command
    (
        sleep $time_diff
        eval "$command"
        if [[ "$notify" == "TRUE" ]]; then
            notify-send "Command executed successfully!"
        fi
    ) &

    yad --info --text="Command scheduled for execution at $execution_datetime"
else
    # User clicked "Cancel" or closed the window
    echo "Operation cancelled"
    exit 0
fi

Save as: cmd_scheduler.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x cmd_scheduler.sh
Usage: ./cmd_scheduler.sh

Ok, but this is the same as sleep <number>s && <command>. The thing I wanted to execute a command at specific time. Isn't this what at is for?

@jcubic nope, it's not the same! and no, that's not what at is for; see the answer's second sentence.

By the same, I mean sleep <number>s && <command> is the same as your first script, not the same as at.

@jcubic Yes, certainly.  It's essentially the same thing. You may want to use { sleep [NUM] && [CMD]; } &disown, or your terminal is going to be tied up.

AFAICT, your beep script is OK. You may want to try this:
$ at <time> -f ~/bin/beep

Where <time> is simply the time you want the at job to run; e.g. '14:05'.
From man at, the -f option:
-f file Reads the job from file rather than standard input.

at also has options for scheduling an execution time; e.g. :
$ at now +10 minutes -f ~/bin/beep

Some of these options are not covered well in my Debian 'bullseye' version of man at, but are covered well in this blog.
Or, if you want to use date instead of the native at scheduling syntax - for something perhaps more flexible:
$ at $(date +"%H:%M" --date="+ 10 minutes") -f ~/bin/beep 


Edit in response to OP comment:

I d/l a "beep" mp3 file: beep.mp3

I created this script:


#!/usr/bin/bash
mpg123 -q /home/pi/beep.mp3


I ran it using at as follows:

$ at now +1 minutes -f ~/beep
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1 at Sat Jul 27 23:36:00 2024
$


RESULT: I heard the "beep" at 23:36:01

I am running Debian 12 ('bookworm'), mpg123 1.31.2, there is a pipewire installation on my system. Perhaps you have some other differences to account for the failure on your system... But on my system - it works!



I've tried option -f and there are no sound. It seems that I forget that I've tried this in my question.

@jcubic: Please see the Edit section I added.

I did not downvote your answer. now +1 minutes did work. I wonder why time did not work. Maybe 12 vs 24 hours or timezone issue.

@jcubic: I think there are many other combinations of time that will work in at. Again, the reference I mentioned in my answer covers many others - perhaps worth a read?
